# How to acquire gaps in non-overlapping date-ranges in a concurrency-safe manner using JPA?

Tags: java, jpa, jpa-2.0

### Problem

Suppose I have the following entity:

```
@Entity
public class TimeSlot {

    @Id
    private DateTime start;
    private DateTime end;

    // other properties and accessors
}
```

I have several of these objects stored in an SQL-database, and I can guarantee that they do not overlap, but there can be gaps between these ranges. Now, I want to implement a function that, given a start- and and end-date, will create and persist a new `TimeSlot` in every gap in the given interval:

```
public List<TimeSlot> aquireGaps(DateTime start, DateTime end);
```

### Example

To make it more concrete, suppose we simply use integers instead of dates. My table could now look like this:

```
+-------+-----+
| start | end |
+-------+-----+
|     1 |   5 |
|     8 |  12 |
|    20 |  24 |
+-------+-----+
```

After calling the function `aquireGaps(3, 22)` I want the table to look like this:

```
+-------+-----+
| start | end |
+-------+-----+
|     1 |   5 |
|     6 |   7 | <-- new interval fills gap
|     8 |  12 |
|    13 |  19 | <-- new interval fills gap
|    20 |  24 |
+-------+-----+
```

### Question

The question is, how to implement this as a transaction. To be concrete, I want to prevent any other thread/process from creating a new `TimeSlot` in any gap in the interval I am operating on. Performance is not an issue, because the number of concurrent users is very low. I am looking for the solution that is the simplest to implement.

In plain JDBC I would use transaction-isolation-level `SERIALIZABLE`, but there is no standard way to set the isolation-level in JPA. I am looking for a solution that does not depend of vendor-specific functionality.

Alternatively I could just use optimistic locking and retry if the commit failed, but that requires additional error-handling logic.

Are there any viable alternatives, or is optimistic locking/retry on failure the way to go in JPA?

Comment: +1 for a well-phrased question

Answer (score 0):

I'm not clear on what you are trying to do, perhaps explain better. What occurrence of specific SQL are you trying to prevent?

You seem to be try to avoid concurrent inserts, which is something locking or serializable transaction isolation will not help you with, row locking only prevents concurrent updates/deletes to the same rows.

A primary key or unique constraint should be enough to prevent two transactions from inserting TimeSlots that have the same startDate.

See,
http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/Locking

Comment: I have added a concrete example to the question to illustrate the problem.

Comment: As I stated, SERIALIZABLE in JDBC or the database would not help you at all here, SERIALIZABLE does not block inserts.  The only thing you need to do is add a unique constraint to both columns.

Comment: Are you sure? As I understand it, `SERIALIZABLE` prevents phantom reads by acquiring a range-lock, preventing any other process from writing anything that would change the result of the query that triggered the lock. Is that not correct?